# Where to find a dataset for Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)?

Tags: security, dataset, classification, xss, weka

I'm working on a project related to XSS and currently I need a dataset that I can run through WEKA for example, to test some classification algorithms. I've been searching for it on Google but no luck.

Please help me if you can, I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do something along the lines of running web traffic through a binary classifier for identifying XSS attacks? [This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2998/beb0b51ee3a541c7b6f22b85472c53d824de.pdf) paper titled "Multiclass Classification of XSS Web Page Attack using Machine Learning Techniques" by Krishnaveni & Sathiyakumari mentions the [XSSed](http://www.xssed.com/about) dataset that contains URLs with XSS vulnerabilities. You would also need a dataset of URLs that doesn't have XSS attacks (could be clean, have other types of attacks, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this: [XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score -1):

here you go , Cross-site-scripting attacks: A Comprehensive dataset for AI techniques usage
https://github.com/fawaz2015/XSS-dataset